# Como iniciar sesión con volley

Tags: android, response, volley

Hola amigos tengo un problema verán estoy empezando a trabajar con volley y encontrado ejemplos para iniciar sesión como el siguiente.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Conexion.URL_WEB_SERVICE + "iniciar-sesion.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")){
                        SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = Sesion.this.getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        //Adding values to editor
                        editor.putBoolean("", true);
                        // editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                        //Saving values to editor
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Sesion.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        //If the server response is not success
                        //Displaying an error message on toast
                        Toast.makeText(Sesion.this, "Invalido username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

Pero sucede que yo recojo los datos de mi webservices en este formato

```
{"estado":"exito","datos":{"nombre":"usuario1","email":"usuario1@gmail.com","cod_usuario":"8"},"mensaje":"Se inicio la sesion correctamente!"}
```

Como ven paso 3 parametros por asi decirlo

1. estado
2. datos
3. mensaje

Pero no se como comparar esos parámetros en el **response.equalsIgnoreCase** la mayoría de ejemplos solo trabaja con uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el servicio no te está devolviendo un `String` sino un `JSONObject`.

Entonces en los parámetros de la petición tú debes indicar:

1. Que vas a pedir un objeto JSON,  por tanto debes usar `JsonObjectRequest`. **ATENCIÓN** aquí, la variable ha cambiado en el código, para ser coherentes la he llamado `jsonObjectRequest` y no `stringRequest`  como la tienes tú. Tenlo en cuenta para añadirla a la cola de peticiones.
2. Que la respuesta viene como JSON, por tanto tanto en el listener como en el `onResponse` debes indicar que es un `JSONObject`
3. Dentro del `onResponse` debes buscar en la respuesta (que es un `JSONObject`), el valor de la clave `estado`, usando un bloque `try`.

Sería algo así más o menos. Fíjate en todos los cambios de `String` por `JSONObject` y en la forma de leer la respuesta dentro de un bloque `try`:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Conexion.URL_WEB_SERVICE + "iniciar-sesion.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                            String estado=response.getString("estado");                 

                            if(estado.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")){
                                SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = Sesion.this.getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                                //Adding values to editor
                                editor.putBoolean("", true);
                                // editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                                //Saving values to editor
                                editor.commit();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Sesion.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                //If the server response is not success
                                //Displaying an error message on toast
                                Toast.makeText(Sesion.this, "Invalido username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }                

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
        }
```

**NOTA:**

Puede que el webservice esté mal configurado y no devuelva con toda propiedad un `JSONObject`, sino una cadena que parece un JSON. Si el código no funciona, entonces deberás manejarlo como cadena, pero en la respuesta tendrás que convertirlo a JSON para leerlo como tal.